# WPF contextmenu not fired on Windows Server 2003

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, windows-server-2003

I have a class like this:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }
    public List<MenuItem> Children { get; private set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; private set; }
    private BitmapImage _icon;
    public BitmapImage Icon
    {
        get { return _icon; }
        private set { _icon = value; }
    }

    public MenuItem(string text, ICommand command)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Command = command;
        this.Children = new List<MenuItem>();
    }
    public MenuItem(string text, ICommand command, BitmapImage icon)
        : this(text, command)
    {

        this.Icon = icon;            
    }
}
```

from my VM, I am creating an instance of this class and send in a command (refresh), this is a context menu for a TreeViewItem.
everything works as expected on Windows 2008, Windows 7, but doesn't fire on Windows 2003

Comment: The only issue I see here is the lack of a code sample. :)

Comment: it's a generic question, the answer should be yes or no

Comment: @Pacman, The answer should be yes or no based on how you're trying to use the contextMenu. If you provide a code sample of what you're trying to do it would make it easier for us to answer your question. (Although StackOverflow requires at least 30 characters in its answers, so "Yes" and "No" won't work.)

Comment: Are you using exactly the same version of .NET on all machines?

Comment: @Erno, yes both uses .NET 4.0